# GCC failed with variadic template and pointer to member function

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class           Manager
{
public:
  Manager() {}
  virtual ~Manager() {}

  int funcA(std::shared_ptr<int> a, float b) { return *a + b; }
  int funcA(std::shared_ptr<double> a) { return *a; }
};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto resolver(int (Manager::*func)(std::shared_ptr<T>, Args...)) -> decltype(func) {
  return func;
}                                                                                                                                  

int main(int, char **)
{
  Manager m;
  Manager *ptr = &m;

  auto var = std::make_shared<int>(1);

  int result = (ptr->*resolver<int>(&Manager::funcA))(var, 2.0);

  std::cout << result << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This code fail to compile with gcc but is fine with clang.
(gcc 5.3.1 and 6.0.0 20151220).

Do you know if there is any solution to make it compile with gcc ? I tried with template specialization and explicit instantiation.

EDIT: gcc gives the following error:

```
test > g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp 
test.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
test.cpp:29:52: error: no matching function for call to 'resolver(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
   int result = (ptr->*resolver<int>(&Manager::funcA))(var, 2.0);
                                                    ^
test.cpp:15:6: note: candidate: template<class T, class ... Args> decltype (func) resolver(int (Manager::*)(std::shared_ptr<_Tp1>, Args ...))
 auto resolver(int (Manager::*func)(std::shared_ptr<T>, Args...)) -> decltype(func) {
      ^
test.cpp:15:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:29:52: note:   mismatched types 'std::shared_ptr<int>' and 'std::shared_ptr<double>'
   int result = (ptr->*resolver<int>(&Manager::funcA))(var, 2.0);
                                                    ^
test.cpp:29:52: note:   could not resolve address from overloaded function '& Manager::funcA'
test >
```

Comment: What is the error it gives?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I just edited my post

Comment: The main issue here is `resolver<int>(&Manager::funcA)`  (note: this expression needs to be resolved on its own, the following parameter list `(var,2.0)` is NOT a part of overload resolution for `&Manager::funcA`).  It seems that clang decides that the one-argument version of `funcA` is not a candidate, but gcc decides that both are candidates. If there is more than one candidate then `&Manager::funcA` would be ill-formed ([expr.unary.op]/6). Note that if you had any other overload of funcA at all, it's clearly ambiguous, so I think whatever idea you're trying to implement isn't going to work

Comment: IOW the question is whether it's allowed to deduce `Args` to be an empty list (and also, treat `(std::shared_ptr<T>, Args...)` as `(std::shared_ptr<T>)` in that case.

Comment: @M.M Writing resolver<int> (the <int> part) should be enough to deduce the function type, no ?

Comment: @SébastienChapuis no, there's 2 template parameters.. `int` specifies the first one, but you didn't specify the second one so it must be deduced

Comment: @M.M: As gcc succeeds when we provide second argument (`float`). I suspect a gcc bug. (it would also have to deduce than `Args...` is now empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you may use

```
template <typename T>
struct resolver
{
    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator ()(int (Manager::*func)(std::shared_ptr<T>, Args...)) -> decltype(func) {
      return func;
    }
};
```

With call like

```
(ptr->*resolver<int>{}(&Manager::funcA))(var, 2.0);
```

Note the extra `{}` to call constructor.